# Can SVN do something like git filter attributes?

Tags: svn, git

I'm not very familiar with git but it looks like it can use filter attributes to, for example, tidy XML files before committing. The SVN manual specifically (and strongly) advises against using pre-commit hooks for this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be: no. I believe that rejecting the commit is the only safe option with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way to do it, and you'll find that doing such a thing even when it's supported will cause you nothing but headaches.  Even reformatting code yourself before checking in isn't recommended because your revision diffs will not give you a good picture of what really changed.  I only do it if something is so horribly formatted that it's unreadable.

Comment: This is not a concern. It is not a one-time operation to massively change the formatting of the files in a way that intferes with with VCS history. The files are already in pretty good shape, but the point is to keep them that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that you want to do anything like that is to use `clean/smudge` scripts to obscure you database connection string, password for a commerce portal, etc. This is usually done if you can have one config file and it is a mix of functional public data and private security data.

[Pro Git Book's Attributes Section](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html)

hope this helps.

Comment: My question refers to SVN. And there are other reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for your IDE or XML editor. Eclipse for example lets you specify various automatic actions on save (but makes a poor XML editor)...I am sure there is an XML editor out there that will tidy or reformat your XML for you on save.

I don't think diffs should be a reason against this, because a good diff tool will have options for ignoring whitespace and/or unimportant differences, making viewing the diffs easy even if a file has been reformatted.

Depending on the team you work with, and if this "tidying" is dramatically altering every file you touch, you may want to avoid it or it may be perfectly alright. I for example have Eclipse trim trailing whitespace and add missing @Override annotations on save, but I do not tell it to fully reformat my .java files on save.

Comment: There are people using several different editors, and there is also automated processing done. Generally the files are not dramatically altered, but it is required to keep them to team standards.

Comment: Hmm. In that case can it be done as part of the automated processing? That or maybe have devs manually run an xml cleanup script outside of their editor. Even if devs use different editors, is it not possible to have each editor configured appropriately so this isn't an issue?

Answer (score 0):

With Git, you have an entire copy of the repository for your personal use, so munging files during a commit them isn't a problem. After all, you're just affecting yourself.

However, Subversion has a centralized repository which means that munging files during a commit is trickier and is usually discouraged.

One of the issues is that this type of thing has to be handled by a hook, and hooks, since they run on the server, don't have access to your working copy. They can examine the commit via the read-only svnlook command, but that's it. Yes, there are ways to get around it, but as the manual said, it is not recommended.

Even with version control systems like Git and ClearCase where it is possible to munge files during a commit, it is still not a good idea. First of all, it can slow down the commit process as the hook script runs which can frustrate the user. Second of all, what happens if the munging process actually breaks the file? Developers are suppose to test and verify their changes before committing them. "Breaking a build" is a crime even worse than taking the last cup of coffee in the break room and not making another pot. Yet, here's a developer who did everything they're suppose to, and it was the stupid hook script that did it!

This is something that should be done by the automated build process (you are using an incremental build system like CruiseControl or Hudson right?). This can be done as part of the testing and the build can be marked as "unstable" if the file isn't formatted correctly. In fact, Hudson has hooks that can do this as part of the build process which makes doing this very simple. The build server can notify the programmer of his misdeed (Bad programmer! The file is poorly indented! No donut for you!) and the technical lead or the build manager.

What gets checked in is what the developer wrote and tested. Checks for formatting, unit testing, and all that other stuff can be done by the build system.

Comment: In the specific case I'm concerned about there is no build system: it is configuration data. We don't want corrupt configuration data to ever reach the repository, as there is a window of opportunity for other people to deploy that configuration. There are staging environments, but there are also a large number of seemingly-innocuous changes and time pressure. The odds of manual mistakes are far greater than the odds of a bug in "tidy". Commit speed is not an issue. At some future point in time, deployment tools will do this checking, which is probably the correct solution.

Comment: Remember that you can always undo a change in a version control system. You can limit who can check in what. I have a hook that allows you to configure this which you can download from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/hook.tgz). That will allow you to prevent people from accidentally changing it. If you really want, create a pre-commit trigger, make one that simply rejects the transaction if the file isn't formatted correctly. Developers will quickly learn to verify the format before they commit.